# How to retrieve specific cells from ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I'm new to SQL with Java, and I'm currently trying to get data from a ResultSet.

The table I'm retrieving looks something like this:

| Name | Data |
| --- | --- |
| abc | true |
| def | false |
| ... | ... |

I'm trying to get all the information in the Data column and return it as a Boolean array. How would I go about that? I tried `resultSet.getArray("Data")`, but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to iterate through each row in the ResultSet and then get each value from the "data" column and add it to an ArrayList. There is not shortcut to do it in a simply method (that I am aware of). Also  you should change your SQL query to only return the "Data" column to you don't pass as much data around your application.

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet` is quite low level. It mirrors pretty much exactly what the DB is giving you.

Thus, there is nothing like what you want, not in ResultSet itself. You have 3 options:

1. Write a library that does this for you, and then use it. Or, find an existing one - the JDBC raw API is not particularly convenient or easy to use; look at e.g. [JOOQ](https://jooq.org) or [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org).
2. Just write this code yourself, every time:

```
int trues = 0, falses = 0; // a list of boolean values seems kinda stupid, no?
while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getBoolean("Data")) trues++;
    else falses++;
}
```

3. Change the nature of your SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Data FROM myTable GROUP BY Data;
```

and then in java:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int count = rs.getInt(1);
    boolean isTrue = rs.getBoolean(2);
}
```

you can use `.getArray()`, but that requires that you select an actual SQL array. Functions like `ARRAY_AGG` can do that:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(Data) FROM MyTable
```

and then in java:

```
if (!rs.next()) throw new SQLException();
Array a = rs.getArray(1);
```

but now you have an sql Array object which is not particularly convenient either. I told you that JDBC is not a particularly nice API to use, right?I really doubt you'd want this.